# Looping through an Excel spreadsheet (using openpyxl)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, pandas-groupby

`import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Book_1.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet_1']`

I am trying to analyze an excel spreadsheet using openpyxl. My goal is to get the max number from column D for each group of numbers in column A. I would like help in getting a code to loop for the analysis. Here is an example of the spreadsheet that I am trying to analyze. The file name is Book 1 and the sheet name is Sheet 1. I am running Python 3.6.1, pandas 0.20.1, and openpyxl 2.4.7. I am providing the code I have so far.

[image]

Comment: You must provide some of the code you've tried and ask questions about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `pandas` module to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx')
maxdf = df.groupby('ID').max()
```

maxdf will have the result you are looking for.

Comment: How to I get the program to show only the 'id' and one particular column? When I run the code you provided, the 'id' numbers show with their maxes over all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have file `test.xlsx` with worksheet `ws1`. Try:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='test.xlsx')
ws = wb['ws1']

for col in ws.columns:
    col_max = 0
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value > col_max:
            col_max = cell.value
    print('next max:', col_max)
```

I'm looping over all the rows because I'm not sure what you've expected.

Comment: I ran the code that you povided; however, I am not getting the max values that I need. I am trying to get the max value for 1,2,3... in another column.  Then, as result of running the code I got error messages. I updated my question so feel to help again based on it. The result of the code I am providing, as well.

Comment: next max: 1
next max: 2
next max: 3
next max: 4
next max: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-0119c2aba2bb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/hmersiov/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/hmersiov')

Comment: File "C:\Users\hmersiov\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\hmersiov\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/hmersiov/untitled1.py", line 21, in <module>
    if cell.value > col_max:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: It looks like you have empty cell